# How to load Jframe Design window It always show Loading But not load in Ubuntu Os?

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans-7

[image]

How to load Jframe Design window It always show Loading But not load in Ubuntu Os?

Comment: Why don't you try adding an item from palette into the `loading JFrame`? Comment what happened on doing this?

Comment: I mentioned to do something else and you're commenting about something  else.Please try the one which I mentioned above!

Comment: When i open a form It show only loading and not editable if i select anything from palette nothing work and doesn't show any error

Comment: Do one more thing,close this project.Create a sample new project.Add a New JFrame to it and check whether that responds. Sometimes,these kindof things happen when your memory is dying out or CPU is 0% busy---think the reverse of this line as I can't make you understand this line!